# Getting EntityManager in spring boot data rest application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple spring data rest application and need to get EntityManager to be able to persist objects manually or do whatever is needed. I can't get how to explicitly obtain EntityManager. Thanks (link to a project on GitHub: https://github.com/VadOs1/spring-data-rest )

Comment: Why would that be any different as usual? Add a field of type `EntityManager` annotate with `@PersistenceContext`. But you are using Spring Data JPA which already does all that for you. Use the tools at hand, don't work around them.

Comment: I need to make a difficult sql query which I can't perform with CrudRepository standard methods. Adding own methods like findUserById do not solve the issue as well... let assume that I need to perform a query using two tables at once select a.t1, a.t2 from t1,t2 where b.t1 = b.t2; thanks

Comment: Again use the tools at hand don't work around it. You can perfectly do that with Spring Data. Create a method, add `@Query` on that method and use that to define your query.

Comment: could you please share some short example. thanks

Comment: I suggest [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) of the reference guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

       @Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u ORDER BY u.name DESC")
       List<User> getSortedUsers();

    }
```